# Virtualmin: Automatically create SSL based website with a shared SSL wildcard cert?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ssl-certificate

I managed to configure this very nicely under cPanel/WHM, but I am having trouble configuring it under Virtualmin: when I create a new Virtual Server in Virtualmin, I want it to automatically create an Apache  with a subdomain of a shared wildcard SSL domain. So for example, if I create a virtual server for some.example.com, I want *two* VirtualHosts:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName some.example.com
    ServerAlias www.some.example.com some_example.shared-ssl-domain.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
    ServerName some_example.shared-ssl-domain.com
    ...
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/shared-ssl-domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile //path/to/shared-ssl-domain.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/shared-ssl-domain.com.cabundle
</VirtualHost>
```

in cPanel/WHM I was able to do this easily because the template file contained the `<VirtualHost>` and `</VirtualHost>` directives. But Virtualmin's template does now. is there any way I can set up Virtualmin to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a Ruby script which I configured to be run as a hander after any changes are made to a virtual server. The guts of the script are available [as an answer to this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/122002/parse-edit-apache-conf-files-with-ruby), but what it basically does is locate the VirtualHost file for the given domain, find all the directives inside the `<VirtualHost>` tag, and copy them to a new `<Virtualhost>` tag configured to use the wildcard cert.